# Homebrew, Anaconda and other girls and boys

Tags: macos, homebrew, anaconda, jags

ers!
There are several posts discussing how to react on:

```
brew doctor
```

i.e., to some warnings. See, for example:

[Homebrew unbrewed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243910/homebrew-unbrewed-files)

[Brew doctor - “warning: unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406484/brew-doctor-warning-unbrewed-header-files-were-found-in-usr-local-include)

[Best Practices for dealing with unbrewed files in a fresh install of homebrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151865/best-practices-for-dealing-with-unbrewed-files-in-a-fresh-install-of-homebrew)

...

In my case (and I just started playing with the Homebrew on my Mac OSX), in summary it says:

- Unexpected dylibs (in /usr/local/lib/)
- Unexpected header files (in /usr/local/include/c++/4.9.0/, /usr/local/include/c++/5.0.0/, /usr/local/include/JAGS/, /usr/local/include/ntfs/, /usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/ etc.)
- Unbrewed .la files (in /usr/local/lib/)
- Unbrewed .pc files (in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/), which may actually list unbrewed stuffs:

  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse-ext2.pc
  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jags.pc
  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libntfs-3g.pc
  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libublio.pc
  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  - /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc
- and some static libraries (in /usr/local/lib/)

Thus, my question is, again, how to react? In particular, how worrisome is "collision" between Anaconda and Homebrew? Also, I am concerned about the effect on JAGS (which is not so widely used as Anaconda, but still...).

All **systematic** views are more then welcomed!

Many thanks, PM

Comment: I don't see any warnings related to `anaconda` here. I think the first sentence of the output of `brew doctor` applies here: `[...] If everything you use Homebrew for is working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them.`

Comment: Ouch, sorry! There is also this: **Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework**. Of course, this is my precious Anaconda...

Comment: But I just checked my output of `brew doctor` and I also get warnings about `config` scripts outside of `homebrew`'s reach.  I think there is no need to be worried. In fact I haven't encountered a situation where this led to an interference.

Comment: The Python in /Library/Frameworks is not Anaconda. That is coming from the installer from python.org.

Comment: It is Anaconda on my system, because I put it there :-)
There are standard versions (2.6, 2.7 etc.) and added Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Don't react unless and until your builds break.

If you try to build something with optional Python support with --with-python, Homebrew tries to use the python that's first in PATH. Those builds are very likely to fail if that python is Anaconda because of the *-config scripts it installs. Sorry! Anaconda is less likely to cause problems otherwise.